# How can one save a new LCIA method in Brightway

Tags: brightway

I have a list of characterization factors in the following format:

```
[(('biosphere3', key), characterization_factor)]
```

Here is a quick excerpt:

```
my_cfs = [(('biosphere3', 'e259263c-d1f1-449f-bb9b-73c6d0a32a00'), 1.0),
          (('biosphere3', '16eeda8a-1ea2-408e-ab37-2648495058dd'), 1.0),
          (('biosphere3', 'aa7cac3a-3625-41d4-bc54-33e2cf11ec46'), 1.0)
         ]
```

How do I save `my_cfs` to my Brightway Methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure should be very similar to writing a new `Database`, as they share a lot of code.

Create and register a new `Method`:

```
my_method = Method(("some", "name"))
my_metadata = {"unit": "some unit", "something else": "goes here"}
my_method.register(**my_metadata)
```

Then write the data (list of CFs):

```
my_method.write(my_cfs)
```