# Error when validating impact assessment method data and issues with regional characterization factors

Tags: brightway

This question is somewhat related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551595/create-a-new-method-in-brightway-2?newreg=a36ee6252cb34c57a7fa6a50d9d1ae49) one.

I am attempting to validate the data for a new impact assessment method, prior to writing the method. The method data contains characterization factors for both global and regional interventions. I created a small toy example [here](https://github.com/pbaustert/bw2_reg_cfs/).

I am trying to validate the data as follows:

```
my_method = Method(('my method', 'a method', 'oh what a method'))

method_data = [
    (('biosphere', 'global intervention'),1, u'GLO'),
    (('biosphere', 'regional intervention'),1, u'REG')
]

my_method.validate(method_data)
```

The following error occurs:

```
MultipleInvalid: expected a list @ data[0]
```

No errors occur when attempting the write the method without validation. The error can be avoided by storing data in lists rather than tuples.

Is this a bug in the package or am I doing something wrong?

Furthermore, I am testing specifying regional identifiers for each characterization factors (as shown in the data above). This does not seem required, but when specifying an identifier other than `u'GLO'` the impacts are not accounted for in subsequent lca calculations. I test this in my [example notebook](https://github.com/pbaustert/bw2_reg_cfs/).

Should one avoid specifying regional identifiers for characterization factors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Validating your new method

What happens is that you need to "organize" your CFs as a list of lists, instead of a list of tuples:

```py
    my_method = Method(('my method', 'a method', 'oh what a method'))
    method_data = [
        [('biosphere', 'global intervention'),1, u'GLO'],    
        [('biosphere', 'regional intervention'),1, u'REG']
    ]
    my_method.validate(method_data)
```

## Validating an existing method

Suppose you want to *copy* an existing method, and update some CFs (or add a location or uncertainty data). You would be tempted to use the method data from the `load()` function of the `Method` class, but this data is not in "valid" format.

```py
method_data = Method(('CML 2001 (obsolete)', 
    'acidification potential', 'generic')).load()

...
# modify the `method_data`

my_new_method = Method(('my method', 'a method', 'oh what a method'))
my_new_method.validate(method_data)
```

that would yield the following error:

```py
MultipleInvalid                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-2fa012f6d12b> in <module>
      2 my_method = Method(('my method', 'a method', 'oh what a method'))
      3 my_method.validate([list(item) for item in method_data])
----> 4 my_method.validate(method_data)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bw2data/data_store.py in validate(self, data)
    277     def validate(self, data):
    278         """Validate data. Must be called manually."""
--> 279         self.validator(data)
    280         return True

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/voluptuous/schema_builder.py in __call__(self, data)
    270         """Validate data against this schema."""
    271         try:
--> 272             return self._compiled([], data)
    273         except er.MultipleInvalid:
    274             raise

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/voluptuous/schema_builder.py in validate_sequence(path, data)
    644                     errors.append(invalid)
    645             if errors:
--> 646                 raise er.MultipleInvalid(errors)
    647 
    648             if _isnamedtuple(data):


MultipleInvalid: expected a list @ data[0]
```

You must transform it into a list of lists first:

```py
my_method.validate([list(item) for item in method_data])
```